How to configure SEPolicy rules in order to gain access to network in a vendor service?
I have a vendor service (can't make it system one) which has trouble accessing network.
I have written a usual sepolicy rule with
allow myservice self:udp_socket { read write create connect };
allow myservice self:tcp_socket { read write create connect };

and bind the name and node around these. However whenever the service tries to access the internet, I get tons of avc denials with avc: denied { read } for name="hosts" dev="dm...
Seems to me that the said service is trying to resolve the DNS and is unable to do so because of some file access happening on system partition. I can not add a system_file attribute since that's not good for vendor services, and I do not intend to play with it.
